# Why are bagels a traditional Jewish food?

Tags: food, bread

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22158/whats-wrong-with-pastrami-on-white-bread-with-mayonnaise)
One of the stereotypical traditional Jewish foods is a bagel (with or without lox and "shmear"). Why/how did this food come to be associated with Jews?

Comment: Same reason that macadamia nuts are associated with Hawaii, despite the fact, which I just learned this morning, that they are not native there. Someone liked 'em and marketed them.

Answer (score 4):

http://jcarrot.org/whats-so-jewish-about-bagels

> There is more than one answer to this question, the most popular
>   attributing the creation of bagels to a Jewish baker living in 1683
>   Vienna. According to folklore, this unnamed man invented the bagel as
>   a tribute to King John III Sobieski of Poland.