# Honey on Hallah for Newlyweds?

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, marriage, bread, honey

A friend stumped me with this question: What is the earliest reference to the custom of having newlyweds dip their hallah in honey? My guess is that it's an extension from the custom of honey on Rosh haShana... Any ideas?

Comment: Such a practice (if it's at all widespread) doesn't have any basis in Judaism, TTBOMK. Do you have any reason to think this is a "custom" which would achieve reference in any work?

Comment: @DoubleAA lots of people do it.

Comment: @DoubleAA If it's widespread among (some communities of) observant Jews, that's sufficient reason to investigate whether it's grounded in sources.  That's a component of the Aruch Hashulchan's approach, isn't it?

Comment: I have never heard of this custom, and can not even find a current reference for such.

Comment: @Daniel I have no reason to doubt you (though I highly suspect you have a sampling bias in saying "lots"), but I'm still highly confident it has no basis in Judaism. People do all sorts of weird things for fun.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I didn't say the question is bad, though it could use support for how we know it's at all common (eg. "I saw this a few times"). I said I'm pretty certain the answer it has nothing to do with Judaism. See too this question http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22158/759 which is a valid question with an answer that says "this has nothing to do with Judaism".

Comment: @DoubleAA I know lots of people who did it. It may or may not be a high percentage of people but no matter how biased my sample is, my statement is true for some definition of "lots". My comment wasn't meant to explain why the practice must have some basis in Judaism. It was meant to explain why there's a _hava amina_ that it has a basis in Judaism.

Comment: @DoubleAA or Gershon Gold, if you can back up your statements with something substantive such as "I checked *Sefer Kol Minhagei Nisuin Beyisrael*, which pretty comprehensively lists all marriage customs with any basis, and it has no mention of this practice," you should post an answer.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Much more interesting would be finding out who ~25 years ago made this up and popularized it. It was probably like an NCSY/BeneiAkiva rabbi or something like that, who made it up for fun and then suddenly all these kids thought it was Halakha. Ask anyone you know over 50 and I guarantee you they did not do this after their wedding.

Comment: @DoubleAA is there an memeto-epidemiologist in the house?

Answer (score 7):

I checked through the Nitei Gavriel on Nisuin and there is no mention of such a Minhag. I personally have also never heard or seen such a custom.

The closest I found is the [Rokeach 353](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49371&st=&pgnum=206) who mentions that after the Brachos of the Chuppa they give the Chassan and Kallah honey and cheese to eat based on the verse (Shir Hashirim 4:11) "Devash Vchalav Tachas Lshonaich" דבש וחלב תחת לשונך